# There is an issue with TypeScript in Vue3 using Vue.js.？

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

[image]

As shown in the picture, "aliyun.value[key]" will report a type error. However, there is no warning when I modify the code as follows. **What is the more standardized way to write for my case?**

```
// Define the specific type for a ref.
const aliyun = ref<{ [key: string]: string }>({
    name: "aliyun",
    access_key_id: "",
    access_key_secret: "",
    sign_name: ""
});
```

Comment: `(Object.keys(...) as (keyof typeof aliyun["value"])[])`

Comment: Does getSmsConfig have more properties that shouldn't be on aliyun  ?

Answer (score 0):

```
const aliyun = ref<Record<string, string>>({
    name: "aliyun",
    access_key_id: "",
    access_key_secret: "",
    sign_name: ""
});
```